# Cannot move Google Chrome tabs to different monitor in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

When I use Chrome in Windows, I can grab a tab and drag it over to my second monitor and it will automatically maximize. In ubuntu, when I try to do the same, the tab will snap back to my primary monitor and maximize there.

There is a related bug report for Chromium that is labeled "fixed" [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135681), but when I try using Chromium instead of Chrome, I get the same behavior (not what I called fixed).

So far the only other thing I've tried is changing themes, resetting Chrome's settings to default and tested Chromium as I pointed out above. I've also tried installing Chrome from a live Linux disc, and the behavior is still the same. The issue does **not** occur with Firefox, but I need to use Chrome for work-related reasons, so simply switching isn't really an option personally (though it is a viable workaround).

I'm using Chrome 30 and ubuntu 13.04.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Works fine on my Debian and chromium 28.0.1500.95.

Comment: Is that the current stable version? I did an install from the ubuntu software center and it installed 28.0.1500.71. I'd like to upgrade if I can to see if this was patched between the two versions.

Comment: No idea, that's why I just posted a comment. I simply tested with the version I have installed (from the Debian repos) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I upgraded Chrome in ubuntu to version 31.0.1650.57. This fixed the bug and I can now move tabs to any monitor successfully, as well as move tabs into existing windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having this same problem, and I just found a strange workaround. Un-maximize the window. Then drag it halfway between the monitors so it's on both, half on one monitor, half on the other. Then let go, move the mouse to the second monitor, grab the title bar that's visible on that monitor, drag it completely over. It worked for me without snapping to the side of the first monitor.

Comment: What a strange solution, but it worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04, `Shift + Super (Windows Key on the keyboard) + Up/Down/Left/Right` moves the currently active window to the respective monitor!